# What is the best: Check the database or just check the session on each page using PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, handle

I've developed many login systems in PHP. Basically, for each website or application I created, it had a login scheme to create articles, upload images, edit comments e blablabla.

I've never had problems with that, except once when I created a kind of social page inside my website. There was a user bothering the other users, so I decided to delete his profile, that's why I'm here asking your help.

At the time, I was just checking the session on each page, for example:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] === true)
{
    // Keep that page
}
else
{
    // redirect to login page   
}
?>
```

Then, when I deleted his profile the session wasn't closed yet, after that the user continued annoying the other users, and I wasn't able to do anything.

So, what's the most common and best way to handle sessions on each page: Check the database each time or just check if the session is true?

Comment: You should of added a .htaccess rewrite rule with there ip address forwarding them to your logout page, simpleszzz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whats the best way, but I do something like this:

I have an sql table with the sessions (for example userid, sessionid, expiredate, ...).

The sessionid is "saved" in a $_SESSION['cms_session'] .

If the sessionid which is in $_SESSION['cms_session'] doesn't exist in the session table, the user isn't loged in anymore.

For deleting the old sessions in the table i use crons.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is have a single place where you can maintain user status and know that a change will be reflected immediately.

Checking a "user_status" field in the DB is a pretty efficient call to make on each request.  This provides a single place where you know that if you deactivate a user, the changes will be reflected upon their next request.  You can also do this easily without writing another set of routines to look through session variables or to create some sort of messaging system where the application announces that a user has been deactivated.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm using this method now, I just wanted to know if other developers agree with me in that case. thanks

Comment: For small sites, this would be effective, but if you intend to scale for a 'large' amount of users (and 'large' is defined by the capacity of your server/cluster of course), you simply have to go to a memory-based solution like memcache. Brian's approach is actually very similar to what we did at Armor Games, where we stored all session data in memcache along with a user's "active" flag. Querying memcache for multiple keys with a call like `memcache_get($memcache_obj, array($key1,$key2,$key3,etc))` was incredibly efficient for us.

Comment: @iandouglas - I agree with you for a large site, but this adds a lot of complexity to the system for a small or even moderately sized site.

Comment: @BrianHoover Yeah, I agree. If you're on a shared hosting account you may not have access to a tool like memcache. But you're on a VPS or other environment that you can completely customize (like EC2) then you only need a few minutes to install memcached, use Pear to install the memcache library for PHP, and add a few lines of code. Not much else needed.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the database each time a page loads is really inefficient. If all you're trying to do is kill his session, you should store sessions in memcached where the 'key' is based on the username, something like "johnsmith-session" and then on an admin page, send a message to memcached to kill that key, which should immediately log him out of your site.

If PHP is currently writing session data to disk, depending on how the data is serialized, you may be able to track down his session file on disk and delete that file, which will accomplish the same thing: the next time that user tries to load a new page, his session will be invalid and he'll be required to log in again.

Keep in mind that really persistent trouble users will often re-register a new account to continue their antics, so you'll want other means of watching for new registrations from that person.